# Where can I find the original scanned BCP printed in 1662?

Tags: anglicanism, resource-request, prayer-book

Where can I find the original scanned Book of Common Prayer printed in 1662?

Answer (score 2):

A lot of sites have the text of the 1662 BCP (or at least they claim to) but I couldn't see any sites with accessible scans.

Your best bet is probably to buy a [paperback facsimile](http://www.bookdepository.com/Facsimile-of-the-Original-Manuscript-of-the-Book-of-Common-Prayer-Signed-by-Convocation-December-20th-1661-and-Attached-the-Act-of-Uniformity-1662--Church-of-England/9781293509852).

Answer (score 2):

Scans of the 1662 version of the Book of Common Prayer are currently unavailable on Google Books and the Internet Archive, however, you might consider the scans of an 1892 reprint entitled [*The Book of Common Prayer from the Original Manuscript attached to the Act of Uniformity of 1662*](https://books.google.com/books?id=aeCZahwsCioC&printsec=frontcover).

Its publishers claim:

> In the following pages the Book of Common Prayer which was annexed in manuscript, as the authoritative record, to the Act of Uniformity of 1662, is exactly reproduced in type—it is believed for the first time.
>
> By this it is to be understood that the text is here printed *verbatim et literatim*, without any attempt to modernize the spelling, or to harmonize it in the very numerous instances in which it is at variance with itself.

Interestingly, they note that the earliest printed copies of the BCP differ slightly from this text, since the text annexed to the Act of 1662 underwent some revision before being printed for distribution.  Thus, the text of the 1892 work linked here is technically "more original" than the earliest copies of the 1662 BCP.

Comment: It looked to me like most of the 1662 editions out there now are based on the copy that was attached to the Act of Uniformity.

Comment: @curiousdannii Yeah, I wouldn't be surprised if all the facsimiles out there are actually reprints of this 19th-century book, not the 1662 version.  Who wants to deal with that [long s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s) everywhere?